# Swift extension on UITextField won't compile on swift 1.2 and xcode6.3

Tags: ios, swift, uitextfield, xcode6.3

After xCode update 6.3 I have this problem:
"MyUItextViewExtension.swift:xx:xx: Method 'editingRectForBounds' with Objective-C selector 'editingRectForBounds:' conflicts with previous declaration with the same Objective-C selector"

My Swift code is:

```
extension UITextField{      

    func editingRectForBounds(bounds: CGRect) -> CGRect{

        if self.leftView != nil {

            let textFieldPadding : CGFloat = 24.0
            return CGRectMake(bounds.origin.x + textFieldPadding, bounds.origin.y, bounds.size.width+textFieldPadding*2, bounds.size.height)
        } else {
            return textRectForBounds(bounds)
        }
    }

     func  textRectForBounds(bounds: CGRect) -> CGRect {

        if self.leftView != nil {

            let textFieldPadding : CGFloat = 24.0
            return CGRectMake(bounds.origin.x + textFieldPadding, bounds.origin.y, bounds.size.width+textFieldPadding*2, bounds.size.height)
        } else {
            let textFieldPadding : CGFloat = 8.0
            return CGRectMake(bounds.origin.x + textFieldPadding, bounds.origin.y, bounds.size.width+textFieldPadding*2, bounds.size.height)
        }
    }
}
```

I cannot understand the reason of this error.
In project is not defined another category of extension on UITextField...

Answer (score 4):

`editingRectForBounds` already exists in UITextField so you should probably `override` it.

From the [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UITextField_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UITextField/editingRectForBounds:):

> You should not call this method directly. If you want to provide a different editing rectangle for the text, you can override this method and return that rectangle.

**EDIT:**

I didn't realize earlier you wanted to use this *in an extension*. Again, if I believe the [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/BuildingCocoaApps/InteractingWithObjective-CAPIs.html) and if I'm not mistaken this time about what you want, there's a problem:

> You cannot use extensions to override existing methods or properties on Objective-C types.

Answer (score 1):

To add to the existing answers - Xcode 6.3 and Swift 1.2 are more strict in what you are allowed to and not to do.  Apple has tightening up swift and likely you were getting away with something that was "bad" but previous versions of Xcode didn't catch.

Comment: i have been converted extension in a UITextfield subclass. Now work correctly. But it seems like extension now cannot override or redefine methods of an object.

Comment: If you want to override or redefine you need to subclass.  Extensions "Extend" a class by adding new things.

Answer (score 0):

you **can** override a function, but it must be declared as public.  The error is

*Overriding instance method must be as accessible as the declaration it overrides*

Here's an example I've been working on to extend UITextField

```
override public func becomeFirstResponder() -> Bool
```